# Transformation of basis by diagonalization

Tags: matrices

I am given two basis, lets call them $({\alpha_1,\alpha_2})$ and $(\beta_1,\beta_2)$.  I am also given that the matrix M ($\neq 0$)is diagonal in the $\beta$ basis and real, symmetric in the $\alpha$ basis.  Using this I am supposed to show that

$$\begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1\\\alpha_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}cos(\theta)&\sin(\theta)\\-\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\beta_1\\\beta_2\end{bmatrix}$$

So my thought was that
$$M_\alpha=U^TDU=U^TM_\beta U$$
Where U would be a change of basis (and D is a diagonal matrix, later to be diagonal in beta).  Because this changed our matrix from one basis to another, than I can apply that same matrix U toa vector in alpha to get a vector in beta.  However I am not sure why there will be a rotation matrix involved.

Comment: What if $M$ is the zero matrix?  Then it's still zero in any basis; it's diagonal and real symmetric; and the bases could be anything.

Comment: Its nonzero.  Edited my question

Comment: What if it's the identity?  Same comments apply.

Comment: Its for a problem in particle physics (M is actually a hamiltonian), so the identity matrix would be an uninteresting case for the problem

Comment: Don't know anything about particle physics so can't help.

Comment: Thats why I simplified the problem.  For some reason I can't show that if our matrix is symmetric and real in one basis and diagonal in another than those bases are related...

Comment: I suggest you include in the question all of the purely mathematical properties you know about $M$.  I'm sure I'm not the only one here who has no idea about the mathematics of particle physics.  Alternatively, try posting on Physics Stack Exchange.

Comment: Unfortunately that is all I know about M.  That and it is real